# How to verify custom error screen for error type 5xx or 4xx

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I have created a custom error screen for any http 5xx or 4xx error by using error-page tag in web.xml but what should be best approch to verify. I am able to verify for error type 401 and 403 but no idea for other error.

Comment: There are no best ways to verify all error types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a really simple servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/testResponse")
public class TestResponseServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String returnCode = request.getParameter("returnCode");

        if( returnCode == null ) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "missing returnCode parameter");
            return;
        }

        response.sendError(Integer.parseInt(returnCode), "returned code " + returnCode );
    }
}
```

Call it with something like `http://localhost:8080/testResponse?returnCode=505`

Answer (score 0):

For a quick manual test to see if the error page is working, I would simply throw a runtime exception in the controller code that handles requests, something like:

```
throw new RuntimeException("test");
```